# Use Different database in Sql Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create dynamic tables with dynamic columns from one database to another using stored procedure. 
Since i have sequel of queries and conditions i am using it.
But facing issue:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('.

Below is the line where i meet error:

> Execute( 'USE ' + @DB1+ ';CREATE TABLE DB2.dbo.'+ @TableName + ' AS
>   (SELECT * FROM@DB1.dbo.'+@TableName +')' );

thanks in advance!!

Comment: The answer may be in the error message. Can you show the complete script, especially how you are setting the variables

Comment: i tried running it in query editor then no issues, but in procedure since using 2 database , i am having this issue.  If i use - CREATE TABLE DB2.dbo.'+ @TableName + ' AS (SELECT * FROM@DB1.dbo.'+@TableName .. this is also not working. i need a solution for this.

Comment: Can you please update you question rather than adding comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using @DB1 (second occurrence) inside text (inside of single quotes), but needs to be outside, so it would be parsed as variable.

Also you need to use "select * into", because "crate table as" works only in Azure SQL DataWarehouse and is not correct syntax in MS SQL.

So correct code would look like that:

```
Execute( 'USE ' + @DB1+ '; SELECT * INTO DB2.dbo.'+ @TableName + ' FROM ' + @DB1 + '.dbo.' + @TableName +')' );
```

Comment: Yes,this worked for me. The create statement i was using  does not work in sql procedure.I changed as per your help and it worked for me.Thanks

Comment: @ankita25 if this solved your problem, please mark my answer as correct with tick on the left side of my reply ;)

Comment: Ok I did @shimon893.. Is their anyway in SQL Procedure where we can do it with two servers (instead of using 2 database of same server).?

Comment: Yes,  it is possible, you musi link those servers so they will have access to each other.  Here is documentation on string this up: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ff772782(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thankyou very much @shimon893 ...I will implement it..You have good knowledge!!

Comment: .. is there any way of creating constraints and indexes as well with table.. : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/how-to-create-new-table-with-same-constraints-and-indexes- this link tells we can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Execute( 'USE ' + @DB1+ '; SELECT * INTO DB2.dbo.'+ @TableName + ' FROM ' + @DB1 + '.dbo.' + @TableName +')' );
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you added an explanation as to why the original code in the question does not work.

Comment: Because the 'create table ' statement i was using does not work in ms- sql procedure.